# Catch a string FormatException in an MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, try-catch

Occasionally **when using MVCMailer** I get a string FormatException in my view which is then rendered to HTML and sent as an email. The email is sent with the error included - but I'd like to catch these errors and make my system more robust for future errors like this.

Anyway, how can I catch these errors and return a different view or execute different code when they occur? Do I need to override the MVCMailer method?

Many thanks.

Comment: You could format the strings in your actual view model / controller / service layer so that those exceptions will be caught before the view is invoked.  This would make your markup in your views a lot cleaner as well. I have never seen a view error do the behavior that you are describing, so I have no insight into what is going on there.  Any view errors I have had stop processing and throw a 500 / yellow screen of death.

Comment: Tommy, now you mention it, the view is rendered to HTML which is then sent in an email. Apologies for the confusion - I'll update my question.